# facebook-ios-sdk logout

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios

I am building a basic app for school that gets some info from facebook using the facebook-ios-sdk.  However, when I log out of the app, it does not give me the option to log back in, even in the demo from facebook.  I am checking to see if the sessions is still valid, and it always comes out invalid.  That is another problem.  Here is the code I have.  Any help is appreciated.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
      _facebook = [[Facebook alloc] init];

      if ([_facebook isSessionValid] == NO) {
       //show proper buttons for login
        loginButton.hidden = NO;
        logoutButton.hidden = YES;
       }

     else {
     //show proper buttons for logout
        loginButton.hidden = YES;
        logoutButton.hidden = NO;
    }
  }
```

That is to check whether I am logged in or not.  Then I have the proper buttons showing, but the code above is always returning that the session is invalid.  Here are the functions I call to log in or out:

```
- (void)login {
     [_facebook authorize:kAppId permissions:_permissions delegate:self];
}

/**
* Invalidate the access token and clear the cookie.
*/
- (void)logout {
     [_facebook logout:self];
}
```

Comment: Please tidy your post, it's not really readable this way.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize it was so bad.

Answer (score 6):

The facebook object says it has no valid session because its accessToken and/or expirationDate are nil.  That's probably because it doesn't persist them itself.  You probably need to record the accessToken and expirationDate by handling the login in an FBSessionDelegate's fbDidLogin method.

```
- (void)fbDidLogin {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue: _facebook.accessToken forKey: @"access_token"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue: _facebook.expirationDate forKey: @"expiration_date"];
}
```

Use NSUserDefaults, for example, to persist those values to the device.  Then, every time you alloc and init your _facebook object, immediately set the accessToken and expirationDate to the values you stored in NSUserDefaults.

That should fix the facebook object saying isSessionValid = NO always.  As for the other problem, I have the same one :(